# Почему на 2ом гриде кнопка не отображается

Tags: c#, wpf

В первом гриде точно такая же кнопка отображается, во втором, нет

Но если задать ей марджины, она вдруг отобразится, что я неправильно сделал?

```
<Window x:Class="Films.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Films"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="753" MinWidth="100" MaxWidth="753"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid x:Name="MainGrid"
              Grid.Column="0" 
              Height="Auto" 
              HorizontalAlignment="Left" >
            <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="75" />
        </Grid>

        <GridSplitter x:Name="Splinter" Grid.Column="0" Width="4" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,2,2,0" >
            <GridSplitter.Effect>
                <DropShadowEffect Direction="152" BlurRadius="10" ShadowDepth="2" Color="Gray" Opacity="1"></DropShadowEffect>
            </GridSplitter.Effect>
        </GridSplitter>

        <Grid x:Name="SettingsGrid"
              Grid.Column="1" 
              Height="Auto"
              HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="0">
            <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="20"/>
        </Grid>

    </Grid>

</Window>
```

Comment: `Width="0"` уберите.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь